# Salesforce Maps: How to pass recordId to a custom Salesforce Maps Lightning component action

Tags: lightning-action

I've created one custom action into Salesforce Maps package here:
[image]

As you see, this action leads to a Lightning component.
The question is, how to get the recordId of the item clicked on Maps?

[image: clicked on the Asset]

I've tried the same way as used on a record page screen. However in this case this attribute is undefined.

```
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the record ID attribute all you need to do is mark the attribute as global. Example:

```
<aura:component access="global">
  <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" access="global" />

  <p>recordId: {!v.recordId}</p>
</aura:component>
```

*Note that the `aura:component` access had to be `global` in order to show the component.*

Result:

[image: Result]

### Mass Actions

In case anyone is stuck on doing the same thing when selecting multiple locations on the map. The attribute name is `ids`. Example:

```
<aura:component access="global">
  <aura:attribute name="ids" type="String[]" access="global" />
  
  <p>ids:</p>
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.ids}" var="id">
    <p>{!id}</p>
  </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

Result:

[image: Mass Actions result]

Comment: This is working, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so far after searching I have reached the solution to do it as explained in this link, with a visualforce component, the recordId arrives in the options parameter.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000353872&type=1

Here is the key paragraph: "in this example the code is displaying the options object which is providing an array of markers that the user clicked on and for each marker it's displaying its record id, name and tooltips etc."

In the console the record id is showed in 'records' array.

I don't know if there is a more direct solution, hope it helps